# Seria possível identificar 2 números maiores em uma sequência de 5 números digitados pelo usuário?

Tags: java

Tentei fazer, pesquisei a respeito, porem, não consegui. Eu gostaria de saber se é possível identificar dois números maiores *sem a utilização de vetores*?

Segue minha tentativa:

```
int maior1 = 0, 
maior2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println(" Digite números:");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    if(num > maior1){
        maior1 = num;       
        if(num > maior2){
        maior2 = num;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(maior1 + "- " + maior2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creio que isso baste:

```
int maior1 = 0, 
    maior2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(" Digite números:");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    if(num > maior1) {
        maior2 = maior1;
        maior1 = num;
    } else if(num > maior2) {
        maior2 = num;
    }
}

System.out.println(maior1 + " - " + maior2);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/K9pAV0)**.

As diferenças essenciais para o código original são:

- se o número entrado é maior que o primeiro colocado, o primeiro colocado vai para o segundo lugar (`maior2 = maior1;`).
- usamos o `else` para testar se o número é o segundo colocado **apenas** se ele já não é o primeiro colocado.

  O `else` só funciona se o primeiro `if` não for executado, afinal, se o número é o primeiro, já fizemos a fila andar: o "ex-primeiro" é movido para o segundo lugar, e o número entrado assume a liderança, portanto não temos necessidade de fazer novo teste com o segundo colocado.

Comment: Obrigada. Entendi.